# Java_home in Maven

Tags: windows, maven, java, java-home

When I ran `mvn -version`, I noticed the `java_home` points to `...jdk\jre` (as shown below).
Is that wrong? Isn't it supposed to point to `...\jdk.x.y.z` (without the `\jre`)?
If so, how do I reset it? (In global `%java_home%` points to the `jdk` directory)

```
C:\Users\Owner>mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)
Java version: 1.7.0_17
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

No, it's not wrong. It is pointing to the JRE used by your JDK, which is what it's supposed to. If you print out `JAVA_HOME` outside maven, it should print correctly:

```
C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07

C:\>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
Maven home: C:\APPS\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_07, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
C:\>
```

So basically JAVA_HOME needs to point to a JDK installation (maven needs the tools.jar) but maven actually uses the jre within the JDK to run itself.

When using `mvn -version`, maven uses java internal java.home property, as can be seen from [source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/CLIReportingUtils.java):

```
version.append( "Java home: " + System.getProperty( "java.home", "<unknown java home>" ) ).append( LS );
```

This property is not the same thing as JAVA_HOME environment setting, so it might fool you. It is actually dynamic property showing you which JRE is running your code. If you compile and execute a Test.java test class printing the same, you can see that if your JAVA_HOME points to a JDK, the value of java.home is not equal to your JAVA_HOME. This is expected.

Quoting [this](http://javahowto.blogspot.fi/2006/05/javahome-vs-javahome.html):

> What's the difference between JAVA_HOME and java.home?
>
> JAVA_HOME is the JDK install directory, e.g., C:\jdk5. It's meant to be
>   set as an environment variable and referenced in Windows batch files or
>   Unix scripts. I always have it in my Windows Control Panel and .tcsh
>   files,along with other common environment variables. Some Java
>   applications use the name jdk.home for this purpose, which I think is
>   a better name. But JAVA_HOME has been used since the beginning and is
>   now a convention.
>
> java.home is the JRE install directory, e.g., C:\jdk5\jre, or
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_06. Unlike JAVA_HOME, I never seen
>   java.home as an environment variable. java.home is a build-in Java
>   system property, whose value is the JRE install directory. Since all
>   Java system properties are also exposed as Ant build properties, you
>   can also use ${java.home} in build files.
>
> Would jre.home be a better name? Maybe, but I don't think Sun will
>   change it.

You can see that maven uses JAVA_HOME on mvn.bat:

```
:endInit
SET MAVEN_JAVA_EXE="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
..
%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %MAVEN_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR% ..
```

And if you want to make sure, you can comment out "@echo off" statement in mvn.bat, so you can see that it is being used.

---

TL;DR: Based on the information you've given, your configuration is correct, no need to change anything.

---

Edit: thanks to this thread, there was also [an issue about this being confusing](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5756), which resulted in change of output for Maven version 3.5.4.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the `TL;DR` ;))

Comment: No prob. Maybe accept if you feel this answered the question :)

Comment: @eis Hi, I've got a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313902/maven-error-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-rather-than-a-jdk here, can you please help me figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Kraken apparently you got it sorted yourself. Indeed, tools.jar is needed by Maven.

Comment: This was more complicated than it needed to be. Could you add instructions to "copy your JDK lib/tools.jar to /jre/lib"?

Comment: @intlawlisover9000 why? you definitely shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me debugging mvn/jdk issues is to set this before running mvn:
`set MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO=on`

You get verbose output (on windows), including info how Maven picks java.

Comment: When I added JAVA_HOME to my Windows 10 install, I entered two directories, separated by a semicolon.  When I removed the second entry, Windows kept the semicolon, which showed up because of this setting.