# Path to tools.jar in maven on Mac wrong

Tags: java, macos, maven

In my Maven build I have a dependency on the tools.jar;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${toolsjar}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

where the `toolsjar` is defined as a property:

```
<toolsjar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</toolsjar>
```

This all works well on Linux and Windows systems. However on a Mac the path is not properly resolved:

```
java.home:               /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
resolved property value: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/tools.jar
actual location:         /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
```

As you can see the `tools.jar` is searched in the `lib` folder of the `jre` instead of the `jdk`. However the path is properly specified.

Any idea why this does not work as expected, or how to fix it?

Comment: Probably your java.home on the mac machine is set to a wrong place. You can change it the same way as on linux - export JAVA_HOME=.....

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620531/maven-pointing-to-jre-instead-of-jdk

Comment: @VeselinDavidov: The `JAVA_HOME` env variable is not set in either system and `mvn -version` shows me that Linux and Mac point to the JRE as Java Home.

Comment: There's JAVA_HOME, the environment variable, and java.home, the maven property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279640/148680

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I need the compiler API from the tools.jar

Comment: @hotzst Ok.  It does not appear to be in a standard maven repository.  Please note that Java 9 moves things around, so you'll need to revisit this later.