# PKIX path building failed when doing mvn install

Tags: java, maven, ssl-certificate

I tried to do `mvn install` on my Maven project. But I get the error:

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.1.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.1.0.pom ProxyInfo{host='MYCOMPANYPROXYHOST', userName='null', port=8080, type='https', nonProxyHosts='null'}: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

I get an error telling me that Maven couldn't find the certificate, I searched almost every website to find a solution.

**What I have tried :**

- I changed the Maven settings file, my **settings.xml** file is like below:

  ```
   <proxies>
       <proxy>
           <active>true</active>
           <protocol>https</protocol>
           <host>MY_COMPANY_HOST</host>
           <port>8080</port>
           <username>MY_USERNAME</username>
           <password>MY_PASSWORD</password>
           <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
       </proxy>
       <proxy>
           <active>true</active>
           <protocol>http</protocol>
           <host>MY_COMPANY_HOST</host>
           <port>8080</port>
           <username>MY_USERNAME</username>
           <password>MY_PASSWORD</password>
           <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
       </proxy>
   </proxies>
  ```
- I went to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and downloaded the certificate, then I added it to the cacerts, with the command:

  ```
  keytool -import -alias example -keystore  .\cacerts -file example.cer
  ```

**Details** :

- The cacerts file is in `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security`.
- I could obviously go to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 on my Web Browser, since I've downloaded the certificate.
- I am on Windows 10, 64 bits

## EDIT:

The command `mvn -version show` gives:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems inc."
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop\Code\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Sun Microsystems inc., runtime: C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop\TEST\05-Environnement_dev\Tools\Java\jdk-8u73-windows-x64\jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

## EDIT 2:

I tried to use Eclipse, instead of the Maven command. And I could verify this: 
When I change the username or the password I get the error `Failed to authenticate with proxy`,  and modifying the proxy host changes the error message. I can now guarantee that the proxy settings are correct.
(This step actually has cost me half an hour with the IT service, because I failed to authenticate with the proxy multiple times).

Comment: Yes, I am positive.

Comment: what does mvn -version show. Is it the same java where you have installed the certificate ?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I assume the java path is different from %JAVA_HOME%. Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17620644/11244881

Comment: Really intersting, I htink ir's actually my problem, I'll write the solution when I find it. Thank you

Comment: Sadly the problem wasn't from that, Maven is using the jre that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT` to the maven JVM options so it uses the root certificates from Windows