# Not sure if JAVA_HOME is set

Tags: bash, maven, environment-variables, java-home

I have installed Maven on Ubuntu 12.04. The following is the output when I do

```
$ mvn --version

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_38, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-52-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

but when I do

```
$ gedit /etc/environment
```

the output is

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

also the .bash_rc does not have any entry for JAVA_HOME and there is no .bash_profile file.

**My Question**

If JAVA_HOME is not set how `mvn --version` is showing a value of it?

Comment: What "echo $JAVA_HOME" displays on your machine?

Comment: @BaptisteMathus Nothing, it just a blank line followed by command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If JAVA_HOME is not set how mvn --version is showing a value of it?

On my system, the `mvn` program is a shell script, which performs various operations to try to guess a value for `JAVA_HOME`, if a value is not already set. In particular, it examines the location of the `javac` program.

However, according to [the answer of a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279640/545127), what `mvn` reports as "Java home" is *not* the value of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable: it is the value of the `java.home` system proeprty

Answer (score 0):

Can be set in `/etc/.bash_profile` or other system rc files.

Comment: I checked in /etc there is no such file or directory as .bash_profile

Comment: I have a `/etc/bash.bashrc` under cygwin and `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/csh.login` and `/etc/csh.cshrc` under redhat.  I've seen others in different systems.