# my java version is jdk 1.7.but maven uses jdk 1.6

Tags: java, linux, maven

my java version is jdk 1.7 .but maven uses jdk 1.6

java -version
   java version "1.7.0_55"

mvn --version gives
   Apache Maven 3.0.4
   Maven home: /usr/share/maven
   Java version: 1.6.0_31, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
   Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
   Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
   OS name: "linux", version: "3.8.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

I am getting BUILD failer when I try mvn clean install..What have to do??.

There are two version of java installed in my system.java 1.7 and java 1.6.But when I install maven it comes with java 1.6.how can I install maven with java 1.7.

java --version gives

java version "1.7.0_55"

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven

Comment: You need to use both the correct JDK and ensure the compiler plugin has the source and target properties set to 1.7.  Please include the console output so we can see exactly what's happing

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack-dependencies (get-test-data) on project neo4j-spatial: Error unpacking file: /home/power/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar to: /home/dev237/Projects/esplorio-web-master/spatial/target
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Error while expanding /home/power/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar: Negative seek offset and at last it gives build failer

Comment: How to clean..please specific..I am getting many warnings and some errors,..java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset eror also..

Comment: what does javac -version shows ?

Comment: javac -version shows javac 1.6.0_31.I am using netbeans IDE

Comment: Why do you think that error is caused by the version of the JDK you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Java on your path is probably different from the JAVA_HOME environment property.
[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279640/418615)

Comment: thanku..In which file I have to do change?I am new to ubuntu..Should I re-install maven??

Comment: No need to reinstall maven

Comment: I am getting  java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset

Comment: How can install maven with java1.7

Answer (score 0):

Maven uses JAVA_HOME parameter to find which Java version it is supposed to run.

```
You can set the JAVA_HOME parameter just before you start maven (and change it back afterwards if need be).
You could also go into your mvn(non-windows)/mvn.bat(windows) and set your java version explicitly there.
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu..I used to java_home to jdk 1.7..but it does not worked

Comment: JAVA_HOME=java-7-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle   This is what I did in bashrc file..anything else I sjould do???

Comment: open your "mvn" file in maven installation directory,
Add the location of your java installation there for the variable JAVA Home variable