# Jenkins Windows agent: No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK

Tags: java, jenkins, java-8, jenkins-agent

I just setup a new Jenkins agent which is running Windows server 2012. I already installed jdk-8u221-windows-x64 and set Java_home, Path like below

```
C:\Users\Administrator>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\

C:\Users\Administrator>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\
Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\
Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jdk1.8.0_221\\bin;C:\maven\bin;C:\maven\bin
```

However,build job running in this agent always complain that:

> No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK

Any idea of what might be causing this?

*Update Sep 11th, 2019*

I configure the agent node as method 2 of Technext's suggestion
[image]

In a Job build configuration, I selected (System) in JDK option. If I choose JDK 8 update 221, this build job run successfully, but I want to use a (System) JDK which will get from environment variable in this node, so I can switch to another agent node without changing the JDK option.
[image]

However, when I remote to this server, and open command prompt, move on to workspace folder of this project, let say: C:\jenkins_slave\workspace\project01, then type the command: mvn clean install, it run without complain about jdk or jre as run from Jenkins.

Comment: Is the path really correct `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\\bin` ?

Comment: Did you restart the process after setting the environment variable?

Comment: @Naman: yes, the path is correct, I can run java and javac command in command prompt inside this node

Comment: @AndiCover: yes try to reboot server and jenkins slave service many time.
So I wonder that, do I need to configure a settings.xml in maven

Comment: @TienDungTran: What does typing `where java` gives you on the command prompt?

Comment: @Technext: it's show correct the java_home:
      C:\Users\Administrator>where java
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
      C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use any of these methods depending on what suits you:

---

**Method 1**)

Please configure your Windows' Node to point it to the JDK you want to use by following these steps:

1. Go to `Manage Jenkins` > `Global Tool Configuration` > JDK > `Add JDK`

   Since you already have Java installed, uncheck the box `Install automatically`

   In `Name` section, just provide some meaningful identifier, not necessarily `JAVA_HOME`. Now in the `JAVA_HOME` text box, you can provide any value that you wish because you are anyways going to use a different value for your Windows node.

[image]

2. Now go to `Manage Jenkins` > `Manage Nodes` > (Go to `Configure` section of your Windows node) > `Node Properties`

   Now enable the check-box that says `Tool Locations`. Click `Add` > From the drop-down, select the name you provided to your JDK in `Global Tool Configuration` section

   Now here you have to provide the JAVA_HOME path for your Windows node. So wherever it is, just mention that path in the `Home` text box as shown below:

[image]

---

**Method 2**)

Go to `Manage Jenkins` > `Manage Nodes` > (Go to `Configure` section of your Windows node) > `Node Properties`

Now enable the check-box that says `Environment variables` > `Add`

- In `Name` text box, write `Path` (not `PATH`)
- In `Value` text box, write the path of your JDK installation till `bin` as shown below.

[image]

In your case, add the following: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\maven-3.6.1\bin;%PATH%`

*I was not having Maven set in PATH so i added it to Node's configuration as shown above.*

Note: In the `Value` text box, use semi-colon (;) as separator not comma (,)

**Job's JDK config**:

[image]

**Job's command**:

[image]

**Job's output**:

[image]

---

**Method 3**)

In your Windows Node's configuration, enable `Environment variables` and add below variable with the *relevant* value

Name:  `java.home`

Value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre`

**Note**: It's `java.home` (all in small letters as shown below)

[image]

`JAVA_HOME` needs to point to a JDK installation (maven needs the `tools.jar`) but Maven *actually* uses the JRE within the JDK to run itself.

When using `mvn -version`, Maven uses Java's internal `java.home` property. This property is not the same thing as `JAVA_HOME` environment setting so it might fool you. It is actually a dynamic property showing you which JRE is running your code.

Ref: [Java_home in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279586/java-home-in-maven/15279640)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to fix the JAVA_HOME in global tool configuration, due to I have some linux slave.
Second, if I go with your configuration. I have to choose JDK in every job build confiugration which running in this slave, see my picture http://prntscr.com/p201i8. I want to use a (System) JDK which will get from environment variable in this node, so I can switch to another slave node without changing the JDK option.

Comment: this issue still occur with method 2, here is my screenshoot http://prntscr.com/p223yl
I also tried to restart this server.

Comment: Please disconnect and then connect the node.

Comment: unfortunately, this issue still occur.

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `mvn -v`. Also, _during the build_, can you please print the output of `echo %Path%`

Comment: here is the output https://pastebin.com/3wvGCTDa
I just found out that, If I try to run maven bulid inside this node, it run success.

Comment: Your statement comes as a surprise where you mention that _...If I try to run maven bulid inside this node, it run success..._ Where were you running the build before then?

Comment: yes, it's true. When I remote to this server, and open command prompt, cd to workspace folder of this project, let say: C:\jenkins_slave\workspace\project01\, then type the command: mvn clean install, it run without complain about jdk or jre as run from Jenkins.

Comment: Ok. So if i get it right, your issue is still not resolved. You are able to run commands manually on the node but it's not working through Jenkins, correct?

Comment: Based on the [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3wvGCTDa) link that you shared, it seems you have followed the suggestion i made in Method 2 of my answer.

Comment: yes, it still not work, I just update my question for the current status.

Comment: What time are you online? I am available for next 2 hrs. I have SYSTEM enabled in JDK drop-down in my job. Also, in Node's configuration, i only have `Environment variables` set. `Tool Locations` is not set. It's empty and it's working for me. See updated pic in `Method 2` of my answer.

Comment: I online from 9AM->18PM GMT+7. Please let me know when you avaiable. 
I also have some Windows slaves like this and the setup is very straighforward, the build job work well without set Environment varaible in Node's confiugration.I tried to clone the worked node, but the issue still occur. So I think this issue may come from Jenkins configuration.

Comment: I am available usually from 1330 hrs to 1630 hrs GMT. Available right now.

Comment: How could I chat with you?

Comment: I'm glad that something finally worked. It was a tricky one! :)